# ASP MVC check session in custom filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have an attribute that fired when any request recieve to my asp mvc application.

```
public class AllActionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = Session["mySession"]; //it' doesn't work
    }
}
```

Is there any way to check `Session` in `OnActionExecuting()` function?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  is the Session null?  is the value for your key empty?  does this occur only the first time you statrt up your app?

Comment: The name Session does not exist in the current context. No it occur in any request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session can be accessed through the filterContext

Session is a controller property that wraps access to the HttpContext.Session.

There is no Session property in a action filter, you need to look at Session through the filterContext.

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Session
```